# How to show selected start row and end row using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to show selected start row and end row in print preview page using javascript.If I checked data in console.log is correct but it can`t show row datas in print preview .How can I do that ?

**Here is part of my code**

```
 var work = $("#rom-table-id").find("tr");
                        var i = 0;
                        for (var i = selected_start_row; i <= selected_end_row; i++) {

                            $(work[i]).addClass('print-selected-row');
                            console.log(work[i]);
                        } 

window.open('', 'new_window', 'fullscreen=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');

                        // SochiKubun:TD orATC or ALL、SelectedStartKoban:選択開始行の項番、SelectedEndKoban：選択終了行の項番
                        var form = document.createElement('form');
                        var printRomVerAction = location.pathname.substring(0, location.pathname.toUpperCase().lastIndexOf("WSM24G01") + 8) + '/PrintRomVer';
                        form.setAttribute('action', printRomVerAction);
                        form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
                        form.setAttribute('target', 'new_window');
                        form.setAttribute('id', 'SochiButton');
                        form.style.display = 'none';
                        document.body.appendChild(form);
                        var input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                        input.setAttribute('name', 'SochiKubun');
                        var sochi = $('.sochi-kind').text();
                        input.setAttribute('value', sochi);
                        form.appendChild(input);


                        input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                        input.setAttribute('name', 'SelectedStartKoban');
                        var kanbo = $(work[selected_start_row]).children(' td:first').text();                           
                        console.log("start is ", kanbo)
                        input.setAttribute('value', kanbo);
                        form.appendChild(input);

                        input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                        input.setAttribute('name', 'SelectedEndKoban');
                        var kanbo2 = $(work[selected_end_row]).children('td:first').text();
                        console.log("end is ", kanbo2)
                        input.setAttribute('value', kanbo2);
                        form.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: Please create snippet by editing your question to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: Your markup plz?